# Take screenshot of window on Mac without using spacebar then mouse click

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, mouse, screen-capture

I want to take a screenshot of a window on a mac.

I'm currently using <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> then <kbd>space</kbd> then mouse click.

The process is very awkward, you got to do it in that order or you'll have to repeat it again..

I'm wanting a simple keyboard shortcut to do what <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>.

I want to use as simple a shortcut for taking a screenshot of a window.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my solution, which I named **Window-Snapshot**, base on a very simple **AppleScript**, either saved as an application from within the **Script Editor** and or used as part of an **Automator Service** with *keyboard shortcut* assigned. Although as a **Service** it uses the third-party utility used in the **Window-Snapshot AppleScript** application's **one* mouse-click solution** detailed below.

- Note: **Automator** used as a *Service* is, by itself, a nice feature however when used with a *global keyboard shortcut* it can be problematic unless the *keyboard shortcut* used, is both *usable* **and** *not in use elsewhere* in **OS X** or any opened **Applications** whose window is to be captured. Which is why I've included using the **AppleScript** both as an **AppleScript Application** and or an **Automator Service** with *keyboard shortcut* assigned. While some *keyboard shortcuts* assigned to an **Automator Service** will work with most application windows nonetheless it may not work with some, even if that keyboard shortcut isn't assigned to that application of the window being captured. In such cases the **Window-Snapshot AppleScript** application can be used over the **Automator Service**.

### **As an AppleScript Application**

This can be setup to be either a **two mouse-click solution** (*the default*) or a **one* mouse-click solution**.

- * Note: As a **one* mouse-click solution** it requires the use of a third party utility called [CLICLICK](http://www.bluem.net/en/mac/cliclick/). As far as I know, there is no direct *mouse/left mouse down event* in **AppleScript** and thus the use of either a third party utility or otherwise the use of additional code then what's already being presented to employ methods that use other resources, native and or third-party.

As a **two mouse-click solution** the **AppleScript** it's saved as an application, I saved it as **Window-Snapshot** in **Applications**, and then placed it in the **Dock** by dragging and dropping the *application bundle* onto the **Dock** where I wanted it to be.

- What I like about the **two mouse-click solution** is when the *Dock Tile* of the **Window-Snapshot** application is clicked, it's literally like I had manually pressed <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>4</kbd> then <kbd>Space bar</kbd> on the keyboard and now all I have to do is *mouse-over* the *target window* I want to capture and then *mouse-click* it. Thus a **two mouse-click solution**! This method allows pressing the <kbd>esc</kbd> key to abort, just as the manually pressed *keyboard shortcut* would have.  Also it doesn't rely on using a third party utility and a second `delay` command as a timer to allow positioning the mouse pointer before it times out and automatically takes the snapshot used in the **one* mouse-click solution**. By itself the **two mouse-click solution** is the easiest solution presented herein.

As a **one* mouse-click solution** the **AppleScript** is saved as an application and the third party utility [CLICLICK](http://www.bluem.net/en/mac/cliclick/) is added to the application bundle and corresponding code is uncommented in the script.

- Note: The **one* mouse-click solution** uses a second `delay` command to allow time in positioning the mouse pointer anywhere over the target window to be captured and doesn't matter whether or not the window is the top-most window, when the second `delay` command *times out* whichever window the mouse is over that's the one captured in the snapshot. The capture can be aborted by pressing the <kbd>esc</kbd> key before the second `delay` command *times out*.

### **As an Automator Service with *keyboard shortcut***

As **Automator Service** it's created using the **ApplesScript** code, modified slightly, and a *keyboard shortcut* is assigned to the **Service** in: **System Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts > Services**

- Note: The *keyboard shortcut* I assigned is <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>5</kbd> or ⇧⌘5, which seemed a logical one to use, and whichever window the mouse is over is the window that will be captured by the snapshot. The window does not need to be totally visible to be captured or be the top-most window.

### **Window-Snapshot AppleScript Code**

```
tell application "System Events"

    (* Note: If used as the default two mouse-click solution then use as is, nothing else needs to be done. *)

    keystroke "$" using {command down}
    delay 0.25
    keystroke space

    (* Note: If using as the one mouse-click solution or Automator Service, uncomment the 
    two lines below having double-dashes in front by removing the double-dashes. 
    Also when using as the one mouse-click solution, set a value on the 'delay' command 
    below to an appropriate value which allows you the time necessary to move the mouse  
    over the target window before that delay command times out and the snapshot is taken.
    The default of '1.5' is in this use case is a somewhat arbitrary value, set it to suite.

    Note: When using as an Automator Service set the 'delay' command below to '0.25', 
    the same as in the first 'delay' command. *)

    -- delay 1.5
    -- do shell script "/Applications/Window-Snapshot.app/Contents/Resources/cliclick c:."

end tell
```

- Note: As you can see there is a `0.25` second value, `delay 0.25`, on the first `delay` command, this short delay is necessary as there needs to be a delay between the two `keystroke` commands.  If using the **one* mouse-click solution** the second `delay` command needs to be something more realistic.  Set a value that allows you the time necessary to move the mouse over the target window before the delay command expires, e.g. `1.5` etc.

### **Creating the Window-Snapshot Application**

1. Open **Script Editor** (or **AppleScript Editor** if applicable).
2. Copy and paste the **Window-Snapshot AppleScript Code**, from above, into the **Untitled** document window and then press **Compile**.
3. Press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to save and set the **File Format:** to **Application** saving it in the **Applications** folder.
4. Give the **Window-Snapshot** application bundle a custom icon.  I used an icon of a camera found at [Find Icons](http://findicons.com/search/camera) and used [this one in particular](http://findicons.com/icon/37279/scanners_cameras?id=37389) clicking the 'Download ICNS' button.  I opened the downloaded "scanners_cameras.icns" file in **Preview** and copied it and then pasted it into the **Get Info** sheet of the **Window-Snapshot.app** by first selecting the little icon in the upper left corner of the **Window-Snapshot Info** sheet. (In **Applications** select the **Window-Snapshot.app** and press: <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>)
5. Now *drag and drop* the **Window-Snapshot** application bundle from the **Applications** folder onto the **Dock** where you would like it to be.

It's now ready to be used, click the **Window-Snapshot** *Dock Tile* and then click the target window to be captured.

- Note: The snapshots are saved with the same naming and location settings as if ⇧⌘3 was pressed only saving just the target windows.  The *default* is on the Desktop using `Screen Shot yyyy-mm-dd at hh.mm.ss AM|PM` or if the *default* has been changed it will be to however it's currently set.

**Setting up the Window-Snapshot.app to be a one* mouse-click solution using CLICLICK**

1. Download [CLICLICK](http://www.bluem.net/en/mac/cliclick/) and mount the cliclick.dmg file and place a copy of the `cliclick` executable inside the **Window-Snapshot.app** application bundle at the path show in the script.  **Ctrl-Click** the **Window-Snapshot** app selecting **Show Package Contents** and navigate to the **Resources** folder placing a copy of the `cliclick` executable there.
2. Uncomment the two lines below the `(* Note: If using as the one mouse-click solution or Automator Service,` comments by removing the double-dashes, `--`, in front of the code.
3. Save the changes made to the **AppleScript**.

It's now ready to be used as a **one* mouse-click solution**.

### **Creating the Window-Snapshot Automator Service**

1. Open **Automator** selecting **Service**.
2. Set **Service receives selected** to **no input** leaving **in any application** as is.
   Add a **Run AppleScript** and then copy and paste the **Window-Snapshot AppleScript Code** above into the **Run AppleScript** window overwriting the default code.
3. Uncomment the two lines below the `(* Note: If using as the one mouse-click solution or Automator Service,` comments by removing the double-dashes, `--`, in front of the code and set the value of the second `delay` command to `0.25`.
4. Save the **Service** pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> naming it as **Window-Snapshot**.
5. Open **System Preferences** and navigate to **Keyboard  > Keyboard Shortcuts > Services** and scroll to the bottom, then under **General** you'll see **Window-Snapshot** and select it.  Now click on **add shortcut** and press <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>5</kbd> or: ⇧⌘5

It's now ready to be use as a **Service** using the *keyboard shortcut*: ⇧⌘5

- Note: If you only want to use it as a **Service** you'll need to adjust the pathname to the `cliclick` executable to wherever you installed it. You could try putting it in the Services bundle at, e.g. `/Users/$USER/Library/Services/Window-Snapshot.workflow/Contents`, although I did not try this as I like having it as both an **AppleScript** application using it as a **two mouse-click solution** and an **Automator Service** with *keyboard shortcut* assigned.

In closing, I'd like to say that this very simple **AppleScript** certainly can be expounded upon to add additional functionality both as an application or a service, i.e. adding code to save the snapshot with different names and locations etc., however I'll leave that to you to modify if you so choose.

Comment: It works perfectly, ⇧⌘5 and it saves, your solution will help many people. Thank you.

Comment: @Paul, Glad you can use it.  I use a different ver. of the AppleScript App and did not include the code here as it uses another 3rd-party executable.  The 2nd executable is called `checkModifierKeys` and does what the name implies and I have it coded so that if I press the shift key when I click the Dock Tile it toggles the `disable-shadow` key in the screencapture's .plist file so I can take snapshots without the drop shadow easily.  Both executables I built from source code the authors provided although they both provide the binaries. If you're interested, let me know I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use the `screencapture` command:

```
screencapture -w window.png
```

which will capture the first window you click after you run the command, and save it as `window.png`.

There are a few different ways you could bind this command to a keyboard shortcut, e.g. by creating an [Automator service that runs it as a shell script](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2011/03/howto-build-mac-os-x-services-with-automator-and-shell-scripting/), or by using a third-party launcher like [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com). Either way, you'd probably also want to add some smarts to the process that chose a different filename each time, so you didn't keep overwriting your previous screenshot.

I don't know an easy way to always just capture the front-most window... perhaps an AppleScript guru can help with that?

Comment: Where did the window.png save? also with that method using terminal; still have to mouse click, it does make it easier and I'll look into automator and alfred, thankyou.

Comment: With the command above, it will save in whatever folder you ran the command from. If you wanted to always save on the desktop, for example, you could specify that location as part of the filename, e.g. 'screencapture -w ~/Desktop/window.png'. Yes, appreciate mouse click is still required though... wasn't able to figure out a way around that so far.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just enable enhanced dictation commands, then create a new voice command? In the example below I created a voice command that when I say "Grab Picture" it will take a screen shot. Completely bypass the keyboard LOL

[image]